# Remove duplicate rows and keep value in columns that are non-zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID  |in_tier_1 | tier_1_location |in_tier_2 | tier_2_location
100 |1         |Sydney           |0         | 0
100 |0         |0                |1         | Paris
112 |0         |0                |1         | Paris
112 |1         |NYC              |          |
```

And I want to remove duplicates but keep the non-zero values in the columns

```
ID  |in_tier_1 | tier_1_location |in_tier_2 | tier_2_location
100 |1         |Sydney           |1         | Paris
112 |1         |NYC              |1         | Paris
```

I tried to groupby `id` and use the `.agg()` function but it is not working out. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2):

Group by your ID and backfill `NaN` after replacing 0 and `'0'` with `NaN` so to make it easier to backfill. Then, because `bfill()` broadcasts back to the data frame, go back to another grouping on the same key and pick the first element.

```
>>> df.replace(0, np.nan).replace('0', np.nan).groupby(level=0).bfill().groupby(level=0).first()
     in_tier_1 tier_1_location  in_tier_2 tier_2_location
ID                                                       
100        1.0          Sydney        1.0           Paris
112        1.0             NYC        1.0           Paris
```

If `ID` is not your index and is instead a column, substitute `groupby('ID')` for `groupby(level=0)` (in the first instance only: because the first `groupby` returns a `df` with index `ID`, you would need to use `level=0` to group for the second time, unless you also pass `as_index=False`).

Alternatively one could do an `ffill` picking `last`, but that's just a mirrored symmetry.